# R apply cumulative sum

Tags: r, apply, cumsum

I recently asked a question that started me in the right direction, but left me with a few [unsolved issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042230/r-rollapply-bottom-to-top).

I have a data.frame with final growth measurement values listed in the last row (RBH). Each sample is in a separate column and has a different end year of observation (2010, 2011, or 2012). Basically, I need to apply the final total growth measurement (RBH value) to the last year with a measurement, and then subtract each previous year's annual growth measurement from the current growth measurement to recreate how large the sample was each year.

The solution given in the previous question allows me to create a cumulative sum to subtract from each measurement, however it doesn't treat NA or NaN values appropriately. If a given sample has the following measurements, then the output should be as follows:

Sample measurements:

```
2009 - 1.2    
2010 - 1.8    
2011 - NaN    
2012 - NaN    
RBH - 60.5
```

Intended Output:

```
2008 - 57.5    
2009 - 58.7    
2010 - 60.5    
2011 - NaN    
2012 - NaN
```

The code I've been using that was suggested by another user is as follows:

```
cumsum.alt <- function(x){    
  res <- NaN*seq(x)    
  for(i in seq(x)){    
    if(sum(is.na(x[1])) == i){    
      res[i] <- NaN    
    } else {    
      res[i] <- sum(x[1:i], na.rm=TRUE)    
    }    
  }    
  res    
}    

df1[is.na(df1)] = 0 ##This is how you're actually treating it!    
df1 = data.frame(df1)    
df2 = apply(df1[nrow(df1):1,], 2, function(x) c(x[1], x[1]-cumsum.alt(x[-1])))    
df2 = df2[nrow(df2):1,]
```

This works for the cumulative sum, but doesn't deal with NA values. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Will replacing the NaN/NAs help at all? Try replacing them with zero:

```
x[!is.finite(x)] <- 0
cumsum(x)
```

Comment: It gets the RBH values in the right year, but any years following show up as duplicate RBH values. So if observations for a sample end in 2010, my intended output should have the RBH value for 2010, and then NA for 2011 and 2012. Replacing the NaN values with 0 does put the RBH value in for 2010, but then repeats that same value in 2011 and 2012. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Yes, this is easy to do. I will adjust my answer shortly.